# How to check if a field exists inside an API resource?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, resources

I am trying to find out if a property was selected, if it was selected then merge it within the API resource.

Lets say I have something like this:

```
$postA = Post::where('id',  $id)->select(['id', 'title'])->firstOrFail()
$postB = Post::where('id',  $id)->select(['id', 'subtitle'])->firstOrFail()
```

and both of them will use the same API resource:

```
return PostResource($postA);
OR
return PostResource($postB);
```

Then in the API resource, I am trying this to check if a property was selected in the `select` statement:

```
class PostResource extends JsonResource
{
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'title' => $this->when(property_exists($this, 'title'), $this->title),
            'subtitle' => $this->when(property_exists($this, 'subtitle'), $this->subtitle)
            // Other fields and relations
        ];
    }
}
```

But  `property_exists`  doesn't work, it always return false. Why? and how can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel does not actually set properties in that way within the Model. Instead, it stores them in an `$attributes[]` array.  When you access an attribute, the value is returned via the magic method `__get()`, which is inherited through the parent `Model` class.

So `$post->title` is really `$post->attributes['title']`.

A simplified example of this behavior would be:

```php
public function __get(string $key)
{
    return $this->attributes[$key];
}
```

As for your resource, you should be able to use any valid Boolean expression to trigger the `->when()` method, thereby including or excluding your desired attributes.

Assuming your `title` or `subtitle` would never be stored as `null` within the database (empty values are fine), you should be able to use the following because Laravel returns `null` by default if an attribute does not exist.

```php
'title' => $this->when(!is_null($this->title), $this->title),
'subtitle' => $this->when(!is_null($this->subtitle), $this->subtitle)
```

Hope this helps and good luck!